# Suggestions front-end side for my application

Tags: frontend, user-experience

I'm creating a web application for manage a contacts with their appointments.
Every contact has a classic fields (name,  email, telephone, etc) and a list of appointments (with date, scope, place, etc fields).

I have already implemented the back-end side. Now, I'm working for front-end side.
But I don't have idea what it could be the best user experience for manage this contacts.

Could you suggest me some idea? Thanks

Comment: Better when asked here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a quite general question, can you add some more info like which programming language you are using, which web framework you are familiar with etc etc...?

Comment: @ManojKumar, thank you! I didn't know it.

Comment: @alec_djinn I'm using Spring MVC for back-end side. All contacts are saved into file in json format. With jQuery I parse this file to show the contacts in front-end side.